# Multiplying consecutively every two columns of the same data frame

Tags: r

I have a data frame with 83 columns. I want to multiply every i and i+1th column and move to i+2th column, multiply i+2 and i+3 and so on till column 82. 
Or 
Multiply col1 and col2, col3 and col4 so on to col81*col82
And store the results in a new data frame, one with a column for each product.
Is there a simple way of doing this?

I have manually created this by

```
new_df = data.frame(h1 = df1$c1*df1$c2,
                 h2 = df1$c3*df1$c4,
                 ....,
                 h41 = df1$c81*df1$c82
                 )
```

Is there a way to loop this or make this easier?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may explicitly select odd and even columns with

```
df[, seq(1, ncol(df), by = 2)] * df[, seq(2, ncol(df), by = 2)]
```

or, more compactly but also less readably,

```
df[, c(TRUE, FALSE)] * df[, c(FALSE, TRUE)]
```

with the help of recycling.

Answer (score 2):

One option is to create a sequence in a loop

```
sapply(seq(1, ncol(df1), 2), function(i) df1[[i]] * df1[[i+1]])
```